# How to cancel a macOS upgrade? (point release 10.12.x)

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, upgrade

I was told to upgrade my Xcode 9 to 9.1 but when I tried it in App Store it says

> Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because **macOS version 10.12.6** or later is required.

But that is not the problem, my OS is **macOS 10.12.5** Sierra, I decided to click the Update button of **Software Update**  in App Store but when my computer is about to restart, I cancelled it when it prompts to close Terminal.

Why I cancelled it? It's because I remembered my Supervisor saying not to upgrade our OS. What should I do to cancel the update which is only waiting for my computer to restart? Me and my colleague has the same macOS but he doesn't have any problem upgrading Xcode. Please help!

[image: In App Store, the button says Restart instead of Upgrade so now I'm scared lol]

**P.S.
Hey guys I figured out there's really nothing to worry about because when I shut down my computer, there's a prompt saying wether I *Shut Down* or *Install Updates and Shut Down*. I chose Shut Down and that solves the problem. And also relating to the Xcode Upgrade problem, the answer is in the comment.**

Comment: This is a *minor* update meaning you're still running Sierra.  Finish the update.

Comment: That's what my Supervisor told me! To  download the minor update of Sierra! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the .dmg file installer, maybe here  ~/Library/Application Support/AppStore but I'm not sure of the position.. also you can make a search of .dmg and order by date

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I cannot find a .dmg file in that directory.